# Using method of variation to find a general solution - a problem.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The general solution is of the form $$y_g = u_1y_1+u_2y_2$$
where $y_1$ and $y_2$ are solutions of the homogenous equation and $u_1$ and $u_2$ are functions that we want to calculate where

$$u_1' = \frac{-y_2g}{W(y_1,y_2)} \ u_2' = \frac{y_1 g}{W(y_1,y_2)}$$

where $W(y_1,y_2)$ is the wronskian. Then solve $$y''-7y'+10y = g(t)$$

Now I found out that $y_1= e^{5t} \ y_2=e^{2t}$ by solving the corresponding homogenous equation, then $W(y_1,y_2)=-3e^{7t}$

Now here g is arbitrary, so I ended up with:

$$u_1 =  \frac{1}{3} \int -e^{-5t}g(t)dt + c_1 \\ u_2= \frac{-1}{3} \int e^{-2t}g(t)dt + c_2$$

Then I ended up with :

$$y_g = c_1e^{5t}+c_2e^{2t}+\frac{e^{5t}}{3} \int e^{-5t}g(t)dt - \frac{e^{2t}}{3} \int e^{-2t}g(t)dt$$

I believe (checked a lot) I didn't make a calculation mistake. Answer sheet says the answer is :

$$y_c = c_1e^{2t}+c_2{e^{5t}} + \int (e^{5(t-s)}- e^{2(t-s)}) g(s) ds$$

I couldn't understand the part with integration. Isn't the Wronskian obvious? Why the variable s? I couldn't understand anything..

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the $t$ inside the integral is a dummy variable, and thus can be replaced by any letter we desire.  One motivation for doing it in this case is so as not to confuse it with the $t$ variable outside of the integral.  I will say that technically there should be limits on the integrals ($0$ to $t$) when writing it this way. So your answer could be rewritten as $$ y_g = c_1e^{5t}+c_2e^{2t}+\frac{e^{5t}}{3} \int_0^t e^{-5s}g(s)ds - \frac{e^{2t}}{3} \int_0^t e^{-2s}g(s)ds $$ and then we can bring the exponentials with the $t$ variables inside the integral (because there will not be any incorrect canceling) and combine the integrals: $$ y_g = c_1e^{2t}+c_2{e^{5t}} + \frac{1}{3}\int_0^t (e^{5(t-s)}- e^{2(t-s)}) g(s) ds $$

I am not sure why the answer has the $\frac{1}{3}$ disappearing. In general, I would say that your answer, or the way you wrote your answer are not wrong, just different.

Comment: What does it mean when the integrand starts from $t_0$ to $t$ ? I've observed such solutions.